# How dependent is India on China in terms of trade?

Tags: china, india

For instance, is it possible for India to start a trade war (just like the USA did during Trump's presidency) with China and maintain its usual GDP growth? If yes, how? If not, why not?

As far as I understand, India is in an inferior position to China in terms of trade. China has a huge trade surplus with India. The amount is around $77 billion per year. The same is also manifested in India's cowering attitude when they banned mobile apps rather than taking much stronger action.

I am expecting an authoritative answer from credible sources.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_trading_partners_of_India

Comment: India did start a trade war of sorts with China over phone apps and stuff like that. Constraints like "maintain its usual GDP growth" are a bit counterfactual though, so rather difficult to answer (even about the US).

Comment: India has a huge trade imbalance with China, with China exporting more into India than China buying from India. So no, India cannot use that to start a trade war with China. However, that trade imbalance is a deliberate strategy by India - it reduces the chance of a full scale military conflict with China as war with India would mean China would lose access to a large market and lose around $100 billion in trade annually. And India will then either focus on local industry or look at non-China sources to replace China which will mean Chinese business will have more competition than before.

Comment: Voted to close as the question as the question is written in poor propagandist form. Please edit and add citations to your claim and make the language more neutral by removing exaggerated statements.

Comment: Even for US, China is its largest source of imports by a huge margin. The question does not make sense as-it-is.

Answer (score 3):

The key factor for trade dependence is the percentage of imports and exports each country has with the other, not the trade deficit or surplus involved.

[Less than 3% of Chinese exports are to India](https://santandertrade.com/en/portal/analyse-markets/china/foreign-trade-in-figures#:%7E:text=As%20reported%20by%20WTO%20in,and%20USD%20438%20billion%20respectively.), and about [14% of imports to India are from China](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_trading_partners_of_India). Likewise, China accounts for [about 3% of India's exports](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_trading_partners_of_India), and less than 3% of China's imports are from India. India is more dependent upon China than China is upon India, but neither country is indispensable to the other.

Moreover, most of the goods traded between India and China have readily available substitutes from other countries, albeit, perhaps at somewhat higher prices.

So, neither India nor China has all that much trade leverage over the other. Neither depends heavily on the other economically.

There is also not a large volume of immigration or travel between the two countries.

Certainly, strong trade sanctions between the two countries would hurt select businesses - India's cut diamond exporters would be hurt, for example. But the nations as a whole would experience only modest inconvenience.

Answer (score 0):

**Question:**. How dependent is India on China in terms of trade?

**Short Answer**
Trade is trade but the two economies are
Not very dependent on each other, because India’s economy is rising

- **[India is currently the fastest growing economy](https://m.economictimes.com/news/economy/indicators/india-to-be-fastest-growing-economy-for-next-three-years-sp-global-ratings/amp_articleshow/101276724.cms)**
- **[Trade with China is down from 2022](https://www.fibre2fashion.com/news/textile-news/india-china-trade-falls-0-9-in-h1-2023-1st-signs-of-slowdown-in-year-288878-newsdetails.htm?amp=true)**

> and chinas economy is falling

- **[China reports double-digit plunge in July exports and imports, missing expectations](https://www.cnbc.com/amp/2023/08/08/china-reports-double-digit-plunge-in-july-exports-and-imports-missing-expectations.html)**
- **[China’s economy is in desperate need of rescue](https://www.economist.com/finance-and-economics/2023/08/24/chinas-economy-is-in-desperate-need-of-rescue#)**
- **[China’s economy is in trouble. Here’s what’s gone wrong](https://amp.cnn.com/cnn/2023/08/21/economy/china-economy-troubles-intl-hnk/index.html)**
- **[China’s Economy Faces Yet Another Threat: Falling Prices](https://www.nytimes.com/2023/08/09/business/china-economy-inflation.html)**

and their mutual trade has nothing to do with either. So clearly they aren’t dependent on trade.

Because obviously India with a growing economy and a **[large trade deficit with China](https://m.economictimes.com/news/economy/foreign-trade/india-china-trade-climbs-to-usd-135-98-billion-in-2022-trade-deficit-crosses-usd-100-billion-for-the-first-time/amp_articleshow/96969775.cms)** can’t be dependent on the trade if it’s enjoying this economic growth while the trade is shrinking.  And China isn’t dependent on India’s trade cause $100 billion in exports to India is a small fraction of **[China’s 3.7 trillion annual trade](https://santandertrade.com/en/portal/analyse-markets/china/foreign-trade-in-figures#:%7E:text=As%20reported%20by%20WTO%20in,and%20USD%20438%20billion%20respectively.)**.

**Answer**

not nearly as dependent as they should be or will be.   A lot of trade but neither economy is dependent on this trade nor is their relationship defined by that trade.  India **[China trade amounted to $136 billion in 2022](https://m.economictimes.com/news/economy/foreign-trade/india-china-trade-climbs-to-usd-135-98-billion-in-2022-trade-deficit-crosses-usd-100-billion-for-the-first-time/amp_articleshow/96969775.cms)** a record, with a 100 billion Chines surplus up 21% from the previous year. Indias imports are growing while Indian exports are shrinking.  The trade doesn’t define the economic dependence so much as the suspicions on both sides of the border.

Historically China and India have had strong trade ties and thousands of years of peaceful coexistence.  The Silk Road not only connected Europe Persia and China but also India.  Historically they have seen each other as linked. When one did well the other did well.  **[India was one of the first countries to recognize the CCP in 1950](https://www.mea.gov.in/Portal/ForeignRelation/China_January_2014.pdf)**.  **[In 1954, Indian Prime Minister Nehru was the first head of state of a non-communist country to have a state visit](https://qz.com/india/404874/photos-when-indias-first-prime-minister-visited-china-in-1954)** with China since the CCP came to power.

This historical interdependence and good relations **[began to sour in the 1950s when China invasion of Tibet](https://www.jstor.org/stable/24385534)**.  Then **[fell apart in 1962 when China and India went to war over a disputed boarder](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sino-Indian_War#:%7E:text=The%20Sino%2DIndian%20War%20also,the%20Sino%2DIndian%20border%20dispute.)**.  This lead to a **[cutting of diplomatic relations which weren’t restored until 1976](https://www.nytimes.com/1976/04/16/archives/india-to-send-ambassador-to-china-first-in-15-years-joyous.html)** and from that time forward sustained suspicion on both sides of the border.

**[China India relations see 80s through 2020s.](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/China%E2%80%93India_relations)**

Today the relationship and inter dependence are governed by this suspicion and security concerns.  In **[2020-21 60,000 Chinese troops clashed with 250,000 Indian military with 100s of casualties](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2020%E2%80%932021_China%E2%80%93India_skirmishes)**.

The same meteoric rise which propelled chinas economy is on the precipice of propelling Indias economy beyond China.

**[India’s lead over China as world’s fastest-growing economy will widen in coming years](https://scroll.in/article/924459/indias-lead-over-china-as-worlds-fastest-growing-economy-will-widen-in-coming-years-report)**

**[India to surpass China and become worlds largest economy by 2050](https://m.economictimes.com/news/economy/indicators/india-to-surpass-china-will-become-worlds-largest-economy-by-2050-report/articleshow/12443008.cms)**

Both know this and common wisdom dictates Indias gain will diminish China.

**[China, 'factory of the world,' is losing more of its manufacturing and export dominance](https://www.cnbc.com/amp/2022/10/20/china-factory-of-the-world-is-losing-its-manufacturing-dominance.html)**

**[China’s Big Troubles: Its Days As Global Go-To Manufacturer May Be Coming To An End](https://www.forbes.com/sites/kenrapoza/2023/05/02/chinas-big-troubles-its-days-as-global-go-to-manufacturer-may-be-coming-to-an-end/amp/)**

**[How China is slowly losing its position as the world’s factory](https://www.indiatoday.in/amp/business/story/china-manufacturing-hub-worlds-factory-losing-position-2394842-2023-06-19)**

That is what defines the current relationship and the economic interdependence.  Indias rise is not dependent on chinas acceptance and right now both seem to be treating each other as rivals and threats rather than each others greatest future partners.

**[Xi’s Age of Stagnation
The Great Walling-Off of China](https://www.foreignaffairs.com/china/xi-jinping-age-stagnation)**

Comment: Doesn't sound very convincing - sounds like a politically motivated answer. Citation needed!

Comment: @user366312 I would argue that saying the are very dependent on China for trade is a politically motivated statement.

Comment: @JoeW, *I would argue that saying the are very dependent on China for trade is a politically motivated statement.* --- the post your own answer.  I am not saying that I am in need of a statement like that. I said the above answer is not answering the question in a credible fashion.

Comment: @user366312 I am just commenting on your statement that this answer sounds like it is politically motivated and needs citation when you asked a single sentence question with no citation.

Comment: @JoeW, If I post a question on this topic with citation, then I am not in need on an answer at all. I am looking for a ctedible answer from a guy who understands this topic better than I do. Apparently this user is trying to post a trivial general knowledge as an answer. As afar as I understand, India is at an inferior position than China in terms trade. China has a huge trade surplus with India. I think the amount in around 77 billion per year. It is also manifested in Inda's cowerdly attitude when they banned mobile apps rather than taking a much stronger action.

Comment: @user366312 You could include why you think the Indian economy is dependent on China. The US is China's number one trade partner which also suggests that China is a major trade partner for the US. If they could do something why can't India?

Comment: @JoeW, Then I don't need to post this question at all...

Comment: The reason why I said they weren’t dependant is because Indias economy is rising and chinas is falling and their mutual trade has nothing to do with either.  That’s not politics it’s just facts.